# Tower of Hanoi logic

Tags: java, towers-of-hanoi

Okay so I have an assignment on the tower of Hanoi problem. I got the code and got it working but I just don't know what's going on behind it. Can someone please explain? I don't understand the lines where it says `solveTower(num-1, from, other, to)` and `solveTower(1, from, to, other)` and `solveTower(num-1, other, to, from)`. I understand what it is doing, it's just moving the number of disks from one peg to another using the other one. I just don't understand what's going on behind it. Like why do I have to move the `num-1` disks from the left peg to the middle, the move the biggest disk from the left peg to right peg, and move the `num-1` disks from the middle to the right? Why can't I just say something like `solveTower(num, from, to, other)` to move all the disks from the left peg to the right peg?
Here's my driver:

```
public class Hanoi_Driver
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    Tower tower = new Tower();
    tower.solveTower();
  }
}
```

And here's my object:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tower 
{

  private int size;
  private String fromPeg = "A";
  private String toPeg = "C";
  private String otherPeg = "B";

  public Tower() 
  {
    this.size = size;
    this.fromPeg = fromPeg;
    this.toPeg = toPeg;
    this.otherPeg = otherPeg;
  }

  public void solveTower()
  {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What do you want the size to be?");
    size = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Steps for solving " + size + " disk tower of hanoi puzzle, ");

    solveTower(size, fromPeg, toPeg, otherPeg);
  }

  private void solveTower(int num, String from, String to, String other) {

    if (num == 1) {
      System.out.println("Move disk from " + from +
                         " to " + to + ".");
    }
    else {
      solveTower(num-1, from, other, to);
      solveTower(1, from, to, other);
      solveTower(num-1, other, to, from);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These lines

```
  solveTower(num-1, from, other, to);
  solveTower(1, from, to, other);
  solveTower(num-1, other, to, from);
```

indicate that if the solution is not already found (the `else` of `num == 1`, in other words where `num > 1` or actually when `num < 1`), then #1: move all but one (`num-1`) from `from` to `other` (not onto `to`), #2: move the remaining one onto the correct destination `to`, and #3: move back the original ones from `other` back to `to`. 
Each time, the third argument is the extra peg to be used.
When you start here:

```
solveTower(size, fromPeg, toPeg, otherPeg);
```

you are saying "solve the entire problem".
The other recursive calls to solveTower` break the problem into smaller pieces.

This works just fine for me:

```
What do you want the size to be?
3
Steps for solving 3 disk tower of hanoi puzzle, 
Move disk from A to C.
Move disk from A to B.
Move disk from C to B.
Move disk from A to C.
Move disk from B to A.
Move disk from B to C.
Move disk from A to C.
```

With size larger than 3, then the steps to solve the problem become more complex. Sizes 1 and 2 work fine, but size 0 is not handled correctly. (There is no check in the solver for sizes of 0 or less.)
You can delete some unnecessary code in the Tower constructor; it only needs to be:

public Tower() 
  {
  }

and you might close the Scanner keyboard:

```
  public void solveTower()
  {
  ... (code removed to reduce length of post)
    solveTower(size, fromPeg, toPeg, otherPeg);
    keyboard.close();
  }
```

Comment: Well I get that, but I just don't get what is happening behind those codes. When I tried using `solveTower(size, fromPeg, toPeg, otherPeg)` it caused an error in Java. That's why I want to know what is going on behind the codes.

Comment: Are you saying that this line of code: `solveTower(size, fromPeg, toPeg, otherPeg)` "causes an error"? What is the error (exception)? That is likely your problem.

Comment: It says `java.lang.StackOverflowError at Tower.nextMove(Tower.java:35)`. It did compile but it just didn't run.

Comment: When you input size of 0 or less, right?

Comment: This code works just fine; I pasted the output above.

Comment: I have suggested two cleanups above.

Comment: What? I put size is 3 and I ran into that error!! And what should I do if size is 0 or less?

Comment: It works just fine for me. I suspect that you might have accidentally edited the code locally, and posted something else above. Triple check that your local code is the same as you posted in your question.

Comment: I copied and paste the code here and tried putting solveTower(num, fromPeg, toPeg, otherPeg) but it still causes an error. Oh and I just put that code alone, without anything else. Maybe that's why I get an error? And does the program I'm using make a difference? I'm using Dr.Java.

Comment: Where did you put `solveTower(num, fromPeg, toPeg, otherPeg)`? That is already in the code. You should run "Hanoi_Driver" in Dr. Java, NOT Tower.

Comment: Wait a second! The error you pasted says `Tower.nextMove(Tower.java:35)` but there is no method called `nextMove()` in the code which you pasted. You've got a mixup between the code you pasted and the code you are testing.

Comment: Well I changed the name of the method to `nextMove()` in my local code but I did copied and pasted this code from here to my program again and instead of `solveTower(num-1, from, other, to)` and     `solveTower(1, from, to, other)` and `solveTower(num-1, other, to, from)`, I just put `solveTower(num,from,to,other)` and run it in the driver but it still gives an `java.lang.StackOverflowError` at the line.

Comment: It works just fine for me. Maybe you need to change the Stack size in Dr Java.